# A telegram from Mars

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, causality

Say, people fly to Mars, get in trouble, and want to send us a SOS signal. The average distance is 225 Gm, so they must wait 25 minutes to hear our response at the speed of light. This may just be too late...

A superlumnal communication would be much better, but its impossible, even with quantum entanglement, as this would violate causality per special relativity. Yet I fail to see how this restriction technically applies to a quantum eraser, as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment

So I am asking for an explanation of why the following setup would not work.

We place a powerful laser with a BBO crystal on a space station exactly in the middle between the Earth and Mars. Two rays of the split beam are focused accordingly to each planet. Assume we use big mirrors and what not to focus light reasonably precise. On the Earth, we observe the result of the light passing through the slits (as described in the link above). The travelers on the Mars periodically put a linear polarizer in the beam on their end. They use a Morse code as polarized and non-polarized.

According to the description, we on the Earth should see the interference or not see it depending on the presence of the linear polarizer in the beam on the Mars. If this is true, we should be able to read the Morse code with no delay.

What is the conceptual flaw in this specific design? Why would it not work?

Comment: Did you notice that the sums that appears in Figures 3 & 4 are the same?  Now read this line again *"Bob always measures a smear, never an interference pattern, no matter what Alice does"*. Then ask what processing has to be done to disentangle the sum into it's two parts (i.e. to let Bob plot two interference patterns)? What information is needed for that processing?

Comment: It seems to me that this question is. addressed in the linked wikipedia article, under the heading **Nonlocality**.  Can you clarify either why that section does not address your question and/or exactly where you first find it difficult to follow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the Quantum eraser experiment, but I can answer for your scenario.
Since the people on Mars can't determine if the photons they receive pass of not the polarizer, they can't choose how it affect the photons received on earth. 50% of the photons will pass through the filter and 50% will not, thus, the expected mesure on earth do not change.

Comment: The beam is modulated with the Morse code on one end, so it should become modulated on the other. Any lack of knowledge of the actual remote state is irrelevant, only its change is important (modulation). Thus information is instantly transferred. Or if it is not, then why?